# SharePoint installation using autospinstaller

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a 4 servers out of which 2 servers will be WFE and 2 will app server.
I will not installing any service on the WFE server. So how do i use autospinstaller script install the binaries and add the WFE to the farm with powershell remoting.

Thanks,
Sudan